# width not inheriting from parent?

Tags: css

I'm attempting to have an overlay of an image. I've done it a bit before but for some reason today I'm obviously forgetting something. It seems to take the width of the entire page and not its parent:

```
    #work_item {
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
    }

    #work_item img {}

    #work_item a {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 30;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: #000;
        color: #FFF;
           }

            <div id='work_item'>
        <img src="" />
        <a href="#">Click Here!</a>
    </div>
```

Any Help?

Comment: hi @andy i think u want this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/CRY3g/6/     or this    http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/CRY3g/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#work_item {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

#work_item img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

#work_item a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 30;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: #FFF;
}​

<div id='work_item'> 
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQfMwj05-cLtN4hGPTSKJcsElDOeNTW65rlmQKXzRo5ZCbFmvuY0dccZMU" /> 
    <a href="#">Click Here!</a> 
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/38v3h/

Answer (score 0):

Add this code, if you meant the `#work_item`:

```
#work_item {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CRY3g/

Answer (score 0):

`div` is a block element which occupy the whole width of the its parent regardless of the width of its content. There are many ways to make the div `#work_item` to wrap the content.

display inline-block;

```
    #work_item {
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
        display inline-block;
    }
```

you can also float the div:

```
  #work_item {
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
        float: left;
    }
```